# How do I build Lynx with SSL on Mac OS X?

Tags: ssh, software-installation, osx, lynx

I'd like to build and install Lynx on Mac OS X. I've found out that building is as simple as running `./configure`, but I'm having trouble building with SSL support. I've downloaded openSSL. How do I include it in my build?

Answer (score 4):

It should be as simple as:

```
./configure --with-ssl
```

Use:

```
./configure --help
```

to get all configuration options. Of course, this requires OpenSSL to be built and installed. If you installed it in a non-standard directory, you might need to specify the path with `--with-ssl=path`, and/or add an include directory.

```
CFLAGS=-I/path/to/openssl/headers ./configure --with-ssl
```